# Programmatically change a chart title in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simple column chart that I update via AJAX, and all is working fine except I cannot change the actual title of the chart when I'm updating the data.

I've tried the obvious -

```
chart.title="new title";
//and
chart.title.text="New title";
```

etc. - to no avail, and have had no success finding a solution online.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use `setTitle(titleObj, subTitleObj)` for that.

```
chart.setTitle({text: "New Title"});
```

See an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-settitle/)

See the [API Ref](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle).

Comment: if you are looking for set *subtitle* then just pass null as first argument like: 

`chart.setTitle(null, { text: 'New title ' + i});`