# Highcharts and the export of table data

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i've searched around a bit and i'm unable to find a definitive solution as to how to export a data table along with the highchart. [one stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493295/can-highcharts-export-a-chart-and-table-data) points to [this resource](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13156), which is now unavailable. has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this article: [High Charts Link](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#add-data-table)

Also refer [`Fiddle for code`](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/)