# How to access function of buit-in button in highcharts using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to create a custom button on the html page like one on the highcharts. But I do have a table also on my page. Now I want that button to export highchart + table to a pdf file. My code includes:

```
 function DrawPieChart(series)
        {

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    backgroundColor: {
                        linearGradient: [50, 0, 100, 500],
                        stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(0, 00, 0)']
                        ]
                    }
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Matched and Unmatched Regions',

                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                exportButton: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Percentage',
                    data: series
                }]
            });
```

The built-in button on the chart export the pie-chart only , I need to get all my data exported to the pdf . Thats why Im thinking to get things done in this way.Any suugesstions or guidance on this plz?

Comment: You should take a look at `jsPDF` here --> https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another button. There's an option on the `Highcharts` to include your data table in the page: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/)

Also you should search before posting a question: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301371/highcharts-and-the-export-of-table-data)

But if your table has nothing to do with your chart (highly unlikely), then that would be a problem, because the exporting function on the `Highcharts` works with their server, it sends data and brings back a `JPEG` or `PDF` file. So if you want another table not related to your chart to be exported I think you have to go deeper into it's `js` file.

Comment: Raeen , can you plz help me with my code to achieve this, as I have not much know how of this

Comment: Look at the links in my answer, the code and answer is all there.

Comment: I tried but my chart as well as table has been disabled from the page, I am not sure where I am going wrong here

Comment: Can you implement a demo in jsfiddle? I really cant help you without knowing exactly what you want.

Comment: I am trying to include my table in the same way as suggested in the link (that you mentioned above). But I am not been able to achieve this : http://jsfiddle.net/arsalanjawed619/6g8euczd/

Comment: Your fiddle is flawed. You are putting html tags in the javascript only section including `cs` files. Until you can implement a correct jsfiddle sample of your work, I can't help you specifically