# Exporting a table using Highchart library

Tags: highcharts

I have a requirement of generating a simple table to display some data and than export it using highchart library and also I dont want to generate any chart for this data. 
I got this link : [Highcharts and the export of table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301371/highcharts-and-the-export-of-table-data)

But I want to export the table without creating any chart.
Kindly help.

Comment: So do you need to have Highcharts at all? If yes, could you write why you need to use them?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński, thanks for your reply. Actually the scenario is I have a partial view where I have to display 3 charts and a table. For displaying those charts , I am using Highcharts library where I get the downloading options for downloading the chart in different formats. That's why I was thinking if I can create that table using Highchart library so that I have the same downloading options available for that table as well. I hope this will clear my requirement to you.

Comment: Have you seen this plugin? http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data with this plugin you are able to export your data (from all charts) to HTML table. Don't you think it will be better idea? You can of course make this table without chart. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/z9zXM/1312/