# Dynamically update subtitle on Highcharts chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to dynamically update the subtitle of a Highcharts chart?

[In the docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#subtitle.text), I can only see options relating to initial configuration options, not methods to update the chart.

In the update I'm doing, I'm also updating the data, and I'd like the highcharts update to be part of a smooth redraw if possible, rather than re-rendering the whole chart.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    subtitle: {
        text: 'The subtitle'
    }, ...
});
//how to update after initial config?
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7p5pscvs/

Comment: The JS fiddle link in the answer to this question has what you're looking for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905367/programmatically-change-a-chart-title-in-highcharts

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-settitle/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
       chart.setTitle(null, { text: 'New subtitle '});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7p5pscvs/3/

API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setTitle

Comment: Just suggested an edit to add the API reference page: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setTitle