# How can I get JSON Data to highcharts using ajax with Javascript but not jquery

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, highcharts

I am fresher and have been developing static websites.But recently they started training me to work with dynamic websites. So we came across Charts so I selected HighCharts. But I am unable to give the data from a JSON File using AJAX. So please guide me. As a fresher here I am concentrating first to just get the title from JSON. But experts please comment how to get data too....
This is my HighCharts Code.Please dont use JQUERY...

```
var i = 1,
    chart;
    $(function () {
        chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
          type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: "This is a sample"
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [1, 2, 4]
        }, {
          name: 'John',
          data: [3, 5, 7]
        }]
      });
    });
```

This is my JSON

```
{
    "type":"This is a smaple JSON"
}
```

This is my AJAX

```
window.onload=function()
    {
    var Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    Request.open("GET","animal.json");
    Request.onload = function()
    {
        var datas=JSON.parse(Request.responseText);
        parsess(datas);
    }
    Request.send();
    }

    function parsess(ourData)
    {
        chart.title.text=ourData.type;
    }
```

For example when I press a button I should get the Title in Graph..

Comment: " unable to" is not an error message or problem statement. What goes wrong? Did you try to debug and check for console / network errors etc?

Comment: I am not getting any error in console

Comment: what about network tools? Does the ajax request to animal.json complete successfully? What is inside the Response of that call?

Comment: Really I have no Idea regarding that.. I am new to handle these JSON and AJAX data...can u say what I should check???

Comment: It's google-able, but here goes: open your Developer tools, find the Network section. Now load your page, and watch for the request to animal.json. You should see the response code come back (e.g. it will be 200 OK if successful, something else if a problem occurred). Then click on that request, and look in the Response section to see what exactly was sent back

Comment: You can also set breakpoints on your JS code to halt the execution on specific lines, so you can see what is being executed and when, and what the variable values are at that moment. That way you can check if your code is running as expected or not. This is all basic debugging skills you should know if you've been using Javascript for anything more than very simple things.

Comment: If all of that is expected, then I think maybe you are simply not setting the title in the correct way. This has actually been asked before - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905367/programmatically-change-a-chart-title-in-highcharts

Comment: Okk thanks a lot...I will check and get bak soon....

Comment: I also need some help in exchanging the data ADyson....

Comment: Wow thanks bruh the link you gave worked and I can see request sent in network tab...Can u pls guide me how to fetch data from JSON

Comment: That's a little vague, you'd have to explain more. It sounds like the subject of a new question, since the question asked here is already solved. But perhaps you should check the HighCharts documentation first, they have lots of working examples and clear documentation of how to display data and fetch it from different sources (it seems you can simply specify the URL of the JSON as an option in the setup), plus there are many previous questions on StackOverflow as well if you search. Do some basic research first, try something and then come back with a new question if you're still stuck.

Comment: Ok sure thanks a lot bruh

Comment: P.S. I don't know HighCharts at all, never seen it before today, but I was easily able to solve your first problem by searching, and also quickly look through the documentation to guess how you might add the data, you can learn a great deal simply by googling

Comment: HAHA i too googled bruh but I havent googled fr changing title but just I google for using highcharts.. But all answers were using the JQuery so I posted... Thanks for ur time and efforts bruh..I am struggling from past 2 days...

Comment: The answer to this is nothing to do with jQuery in the end :-)

Comment: :D .. Have a great day bruh